# Ember JS: using a component to wrap accounting.js library

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am trying to wrap [accounting.js](http://openexchangerates.github.io/accounting.js/) into a component but i am missing something fundamental and getting an error.

Here is the each loop in my template:

```
{{#each item in model}}
    {{#with item}}
        {{#link-to 'debtor' debtor_id}}
            <div>{{debtor_id}}</div>
            <div>{{debtor_legacy_account_number}}</div>
            <div>{{debtor_full_name}}</div>
            <!-- below is the component call -->
            <div>{{currency-widget value=debtor_balance}}</div>
            <div>{{debtor_debt_number}}</div>
        {{/link-to}}
    {{/with}}
{{/each}}
```

and here is the component:

```
// app/components/currency-widget.js

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    tagName: 'span',
    classNames: ['currency-widget'],

    didInsertElement: function(value) {
        return accounting.formatMoney(value);
    }
});
```

as you can see, i want to have this component loop through and return a formatted value for each `debtor_balance` property passed to it.

**Update:**  I don't have any errors now.. but the component is not returning the new value.

I added the dependency in my brocfile

`app.import('vendor/accounting.js/accounting.min.js');`

And I also included `accounting` and `formatMoney` to global in my `.jshintrc` file

It must be the the logic inside the component? maybe its something simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can pass a value to the didInsertElement function, but you can still access properties that you set in the template when you define the component. When you say:

```
{{currency-widget value=debtor_balance}}
```

You're effectively setting a value property on the component that is equal to the debtor_balance. So update your component code to access the components "value" attribute, as opposed to trying to pass the value to the didInsertElement function.

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    tagName: 'span',
    value: 0,
    classNames: ['currency-widget'],

    didInsertElement: function() {
        return accounting.formatMoney(this.get('value'));
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that clarification.  I will use that info going forward.

Comment: Hope that helped! Let me know if you're still running into issues. If you update your question, I'll do my best to respond.